# Types 'std::array<char, 6>' and 'char' are not compatible

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with build this code when I try give to the function indicator to array ? Any ideas ?

Compiler error:

```
Types 'std::array<char, 6>' and 'char' are not compatible
```

Here's my code:

```
void NextHash( std::array<char,6>* state ) {

    std::string tablica = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    int j = 5;

    for( int i = 0; i < 36; i++ ) {

        if( tablica[i] == state[j] ) {
            if( i == 35 ) {
                state[j] = tablica[0];
                j--;
                i=-1;
            }
            else{
                state[j] = tablica[i+1];
                i = tablica.size();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Off topic: `state[j] = tablica[i+1];` has the potential to ask for `tablica[36]` which is out of range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing in a **pointer** to a `std::array` as a parameter, but then using the indexing operator `[]` directly on it instead of dereferencing the pointer first (the `[]` operator is defined for both raw pointer types and `std::array`, hence the confusion).

I suggest changing your function to accept a reference:

```
void NextHash( std::array<char,6>& state ) {
```

...or continue to use `array<char,6>*` but then dereferencing it:

```
if( tablica[i] == (*state)[j] ) {

...

(*state)[j] = tablica[0];
```

If you're using `std::array` instead of raw arrays/pointers for safety reasons, you should consider using the `at` method instead of the indexing operator:

```
void NextHash( std::array<char,6>* state ) {
...
if( tablica[i] == state->at(j) ) {
...
state->at(j) = tablica[0]; // this is valid C++ as references can be assigned to
```

Or:

```
void NextHash( std::array<char,6>& state ) {
...
if( tablica[i] == state.at(j) ) {
...
state.at(j) = tablica[0];
```

Comment: @MateuszZaremba How is dereferencing not working? What error do you get?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Yes because if `state` is a *pointer* to an `std::array` then doing `state[j]` returns an `std::array` rather than a `char`.